# Android studio se pone solo lectura y no puedo escribir codigo

Tags: android-studio

Expongo un problema, en ocasiones cuando estoy escribiendo código en algún proyecto de Android Studio, por una extraña razón se habilita el modo solo lectura, y no me deja escribir código y ya me toca reiniciar el IDE.

¿Alguien sabe porque pasa y como solucionar el deshabilitar el modo solo lectura?

que reiniciar el IDE demora unos 5 o 10 minutos, ya que mi PC es de baja gama

Comment: Hola Christian ¿tienes integrado algún versionador de código?

Comment: no, ninguno, cuando me pase otra vez te doy mas informacion

Answer (score 1):

Asegura deshabilitar el modo de solo lectura, se encuentra en la parte inferior derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te esta sucediendo continuamente, recuerda que el modo de solo lectura también se habilita si los archivos que abres en Android Studio tienen esta propiedad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes deshabilitar esa propiedad en los archivos o directamente desde Android Studio, como indico en la primera imagen.